# Running python script in laravel project (using wamp server)

Tags: python, laravel, wampserver

I'm trying to run, from a Laravel controller, a python script located inside the project dir, but symfony/process keeps generating an error/exception.

```
$extension = 'pdf';
$filename = rand(11111111, 99999999). '.' . $extension;
$request->file('centrale_rischi')->move(
        base_path() . '/public/pdfcr/', $filename
    );
$filePath = base_path() . '/public/pdfcr/'.$filename;

$process = new Process(['python', 'crExtractor.py', $filePath]);
$process->setTimeout(500);

try {
    $process->run();
    if(!$process->isSuccessful()){
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }
} catch(ProcessFailedException $e) {
    dd($e);
}
```

This is the controller code, which tries to run the crExtractor.py on a PDF file in a subdirectory. Whenever i try to execute the same command using the windows cmd i get no problems, but whenever i run a local server with `php artisan serve`, it does not recognize 'python' as a valid command. I've tried using the process like `$process = new Process(['python crExtractor.py'.$filePath]);` but there is another error saying that the path format is incorrect. What could it be? Apache2.4, Python3.9 and Win10 x64

Comment: Can you test be explicit and replace 'python' with '/real/path/to/python'?

Comment: i tried using absolute paths to the python dir and to the python script but it just won't work (either doesn't recognize python as a command or the path to the pdf file as a valid one)